# In PyCharm Django version

Tags: django, pycharm

How can I use Django 1.11 as default version in **pycharm** ?
Letting you know that I'm using **macOS** and default Django version is 2.0.3 !

Comment: Why not use a virtualenv? Pycharm supports it.

Answer (score 2):

Pycharm has nothing to do with Django version. You can just install django version you need.

Use: `pip3 install django==1.11`

> Note:

You can check your globally installed django version by typing:

```
python3
import django
django.VERSION
```

You will probably get 2.0.3 as global django version. So now you have to type:

```
pip3 install django==1.11
```

That will install django with version 1.11 as global. From now, whenever you will create new project via:

`django-admin startproject your_project`

Django version of that new project will be 1.11 by default

> And some advice:

Next time just use `virtualenv` or `virtualenvwrapper`, by using it you will set your libraries locally for each project

Comment: I do it but win I create new project it install 2.0.3 !

Comment: I see, then you must install django globally

Comment: Have you achieved success so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `python virtualenv` to create a custom environment for your project with django version 1.11.

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/creating-virtual-environment.html

In your project folder :

```
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install django=1.11
```

This will create a folder named `env` (`source` command activates this environment). You may need to install all your other dependencies.

In PyCharm, under project settings `Project Interpreter`, select this environment.